# What options does an Anglican have for disposing of very old consecrated elements?

Tags: communion, canon-law, sacraments, church-of-england, rubrics

Suppose that I have inherited responsibility for a Church of England [ambrey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambry) which contains some very old consecrated wafers of bread.

Ordinarily bread and wine once consecrated should be [reverently consumed as per the rubrics of the 1662 Book of Common Prayer](https://www.churchofengland.org/prayer-and-worship/worship-texts-and-resources/book-common-prayer/lords-supper-or-holy-communion):

> ...if any remain of that which was consecrated, it shall not be carried out of the Church, but the Priest, and such other of the Communicants as he shall then call unto him, shall, immediately after the Blessing, reverently eat and drink the same...

Consuming very old and poorly kept elements is the problem here. What are my options for disposal which are approved -  other than simply consuming them?

Comment: Roman-Catholic solution: Dissolve the consecrated bread in water and pour this water directly into the earth and not into a normal drain.